# How disable splitView for app for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, splitview

I have an app for iPhone/iPad, but when it used on iPad I have a problem with splitView mode.
How I can disable splitting on iPad for my app? ( programmatically or in project settings)

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: It is better to fix your app so that it works correctly in split screen rather than simply disabling the feature unless it is something like a game.

Comment: Agree with @Paulw11, but still if you need help " To opt out of being eligible to participate in Slide Over and Split View, add the UIRequiresFullScreen key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES."

Comment: Your are right, but in Xcode 9.3 that parameter can changes in project settings "Require Full Screen"